# Snowflake - Get random sample x10 the number of orders in another table

Tags: sql, random, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have an orders which only contain a specific set of customers
table A:
order_date,
customer_id,
order_id

For example, there are 100 orders on 01/01/2022 and 120 orders on 02/01/2022 from table A.

I would like to get a random sample x10 the number of orders from customers not in table A for each day. So on 01/01/2022 I would like to get 1000 orders.
table B:
order_date,
customer_id,
order_id

| a.order_date | b.order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1212121 |
| 01/01/2022 | 2323232 |
| 02/01/2022 | 456789 |
| 02/01/2022 | 878787 |

01/01/2022 would have an additional 998 rows of order ids
and 02/01/2022 would have an additional 1198 rows of order ids

Comment: So are you want to get an equal sample of daily day for each customers, thus if on day A customer Z has 2 rows, and customer Y has 5 and customer X has 10, you would like 10 for each, of which Y is x2 and Z is x5?

Comment: Hi Simeon. Thanks for responding.
So it was just for total number of orders on the given day.
So if 10 customers ordered on day A, I just want to grab 100 random customers from the other table.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim
I have however managed to solve this with the help from my colleague.
What we did was just aggregate the number of orders by day from table A, then from the other table we grabbed all orders that were not in table A and then assigned a random number, then assigned a rank and did a count distinct of orders by day from table A and *10.
Then I grabbed the orders from table B where the rank was <= the number of orders